# «Сидите терпеливо ждите» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сказуемые

Ощущение такое, что фраза цельная, в духе "я пойду посмотрю". Но, если так, как обосновать ненужность запятой?

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, что запятая нужна. Но вот только где? Это ситуация, похожая на *казнить нельзя помиловать.*
Между глаголами стоит наречие, поэтому ни о какой цельности (единстве сказуемого) и говорить нельзя: или **сидите, терпеливо ждите**; или **сидите терпеливо, ждите.**

Вот здесь есть единство.
*Алло, это школа? Это Витя,

Ваш первоклассник. Нет, Филимонов.

Скоро буду, **сидите ждите.**

(Витя в постели лежал с телефоном.)*
А. Гиварзов

**Дополнение**

Вот что пишет Н. С. Валгина ([Понятие о синтаксической однородности и однородных членах предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm)).
Однородными членами нельзя считать:
в) **сочетания глаголов**, выступающих в роли единого сказуемого: Взял да и сделал, что обещал; Пойду посмотрю, чем занимаются дети; Возьму и скажу свое мнение; Сядь посиди со мной. Примеры: *Я **забегу возьму** рукавицы* (Г.); ***Зайду проведаю*** (Л. Т.); ***Пойду доложу*** (Казак.).

Чаще всего это сочетание двух глаголов в одинаковой форме, первый из которых обозначает **действие**, а второй — **цель действия**:
*"Пойду погуляю  в лесу", — сказала Белоснежка друзьям.*

Answer (score 2):

Сдаётся мне, это разговорная фраза с неудачной инверсией, граничащей с ошибкой: «**Сидите ждите** терпеливо», потому и пунктуация странная. Видимо, запятая всё же не нужна.

Вот если мы переставим слова в следующих  примерах, мы же не поставим запятые?

Ждем весны не дождемся; Дышит горным воздухом не надышится. Я забегу рукавицы возьму (Г.) Если поставим запятые - совсем другой смысл будет и другой синтаксис, появится однородность, а у автора её нет.

Comment: _Сидите ждите терпеливо._ У нас в вопросе **нет** такой фразы. Извините, но в приведенных Вами примерах нет ни одного предложения с именно наречием. И еще. Мне думается, что нельзя произвольно изменять предложение классика и писать, что оно ему принадлежит. В Вашем ответе: _Я забегу рукавицы возьму (Г.)_ — нет у Гоголя **такого** предложения. Еще раз извините.

Comment: Мне вот тоже кажется, что запятая не нужна. Хотя на этот счёт справедливо возражают про отсутствие примеров с наречием. Версия про разговорную инверсию мне очень нравится. Хотя вряд ли я могу, основываясь на одном лишь своём предпочтении, принять хоть один из предложенных ответов.

Comment: Римма, такой фразы, конечно, нет, я перефразировала имеющуюся, чтобы показать нормальный вид сказуемого. Дело в том, что  в разговорной речи нет строго закрепленного расположения компонентов словосочетания, поэтому главным средством актуального членения является не порядок слов, а интонация и логическое ударение.  Я думаю, автор фразы логически выделил "терпеливо" с помощью  инверсии - это разговорный синтаксис. А что переставить - наречие или другую часть речи - разницы нет.

Comment: В правилах таких примеров и не может быть, там нормальный синтаксис - литературный, не разговорный. А что не убрала (Г.) - это да, согласна, это уже не его предложение, нужно было без автора. Кстати, "терпеливо" вряд ли можно сидеть, вот ждать терпеливо - да.

Comment: Контекста нет. Фраза разговорная. Мы решаем абстрактную задачу. А **сидеть терпеливо** вполне возможно (и стоять, и даже лежать). _Сидел терпеливо, положив на колени посох..._ (М. Бабкин)  _Дети сидели терпеливо_ (А. Проуз). _Совершенно не было никаких сил, и она продолжала терпеливо лежать_ (Б. Л. Васильев).

Answer (score 2):

У меня нет сомнений в *необходимости* запятой: она нужна для внесения ясности в разделение словосочетаний на понятия - *что именно* предлагается, **терпеливо сидеть** или **терпеливо ждать**. Второе представляется более логичным: сидеть можно по разным поводам, и необходимость "терпеливого ожидания" (готовность ждать достаточно *долго* и не паниковать от нетерпения) конкретизирует причину, по которой предложено "*сидеть*" (чтобы не устать от долгого, *терпеливого ожидания*). Если же поставить запятую после терпеливо, то выйдет, что выражение разделено на почти полные синонимы (*сидеть терпеливо* = *ждать*). Выглядит это отчасти тавтологично (зачем повторять один и тот же смысл - от избытка эмоций?), отчасти как упрек в "неусидчивости" (мол не ёрзайте), что не ко всякому контексту подходит. Поэтому мне видится предпочтительным выбрать место для запятой (или союза "и") *после "сидите"*.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что Третий глаз имеет в виду первый вариант Риммы с запятой после "сидите". Тот, что можно заменить на "сидите **и** терпеливо ждите". Действительно, цельность есть в тех случаях, когда глаголы не разбиваются наречием, и тогда запятая часто не нужна. Вот ещё пример: моя бабушка часто говорила *иди ешь.*

В общем, на мой взгляд, Римма права, что запятая нужна, однако было бы интересно всё же, если бы кто-то смог убедительно обосновать возможность её непостановки. Интересный вопрос.